# How to use Vuetify 2 breakpoints with script setup syntax?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js, vuejs3

I do get the current instance of Vue and I do get the $vuetify object from it with all the breakpoints as well as other properties.

My issue is that the `breakpoints` properties do not update after changing the screen size. It's not reactive.

I have tried using computed for it and indeed it doesn't change:

```
import { getCurrentInstance } from 'vue'

const vuetify = computed(() => (getCurrentInstance()?.proxy as any).$vuetify);
```

How can I use `$vuetify.breakpoints` and have it change based on screen size – just like in Vue 3 options syntax: `this.$vuetify.breakpoints` – I am upgrading from Vue 2 to 3 with script setup syntax (Composition API).

Thank you.

Comment: Could you provide a little more detail please? Are you using a window 'resize' event listener? Are you adding this to your main JS file where the app is initialised or per component?

Comment: I want to use $vuetify in Vue3 script setup syntax (Composition API) just like this.$vuetify in Vue 2 options API.

In .vue files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make useVuetify composable like this:

```
 // @composables/useVuetify
 import { getCurrentInstance } from 'vue';

  export const useVuetify = () => {
   const vm = getCurrentInstance();
   return vm.proxy?.$vuetify || undefined;
 }
```

Then use it like so:

```
 // Your component
 const vuetify = useVuetify();
 const currentBreakpointName = computed(() => vuetify.breakpoint.name);
```

In script you would need to use it with `.value`: `currentBreakpointName.value`

In template you do not need `.value`: `v-if="currentBreakpointName === 'xl'"` or `:value="currentBreakpointName"` or simple `{{ currentBreakpointName }}`